# Quantum mechanics states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, symmetry

An electronic state is defined by Ψ(θ,φ) means it is dependent on θ and φ, but after repeated measurements it is found that electron's position is independent of Θ and φ. What is its physical and mathematical significance? How this happened?

Comment: It sounds like a spherically symmetric wavefunction...

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your text switches from lower-case $\theta$ to upper-case $\Theta$?

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).